# Sending Large Volume of Push Notifications Without Topics

Tags: amazon-web-services, mobile, push-notification, amazon-sns

**Problem: Sending large numbers of push notifications where the recipient list is always different**

I am working on a new mobile application (iOS) that will include push notifications. From my research, it appears that the common way to send a large number of push notifications is using the publish-subscribe model with users subscribed to a topic.

The issue for my application is that users cannot be divided into fixed topics. I will need to send thousands (or even low millions) of notifications to some arbitrary list of users. The next time I may need to send a similarly large number of notifications to a different list. The notification content will be the same for all recipients, but the list is usually different each time.

**Failed ideas: Sending notifications one by one or using filters**

I am aware that these notifications could be sent one by one using a notification API, but they are time sensitive and presumably this would be inefficient. I am also aware that you can use filters within topics, but I have thousands of possible attribute combinations, so I also assume this is not reasonable (I think I read there are limits to the number of filters). Is there some way to send notifications in bulk (e.g. send the same notification to 100s or 1000s of users at a time within a loop)?

My preference would be for a solution that only uses AWS, but other providers could be considered.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

#### AWS Lambda for creating SNS topics dynamically

Before pushing notification, call a Lambda function to create new SNS topic with the exact list of recipients that you need. After pushing, delete the SNS topic.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40177624/8007403) describes how it can be done. Note that they finally switched to Twillio. I don't know Twillio, but apparently it provides dynamic subscription lists for SMS. Worth checking out.

It seems that you can create SNS topic with dynamic subscription list using the [CloudFormation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71560384/how-to-use-email-dynamic-list-to-sns-topic-subscription-in-aws-cloudformation) as well.

#### SNS with direct addressing

Direct addressing allows you to deliver notifications directly to a single endpoint, rather than sending identical messages to all subscribers of a topic. This doesn't support all endpoints, but [it supports push notifications via Apple Push Notification service (APN)](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/#Does_SNS_support_direct_addressing_for_SMS_or_Email).

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24774837/8007403) describes how it can be implemented. Mind the comment about issues with scaling.